# How to clear table adapter and refill with updated data while foreign key is set to cascade on delete

Tags: c#, winforms, datarepeater

everyone,
I have two tables (Project_Info and Task_Info).
I want the Task_Info_Datarepeater to update its data after I brought changes in tasks and returned in project form. Keep in mind that the Task_info_Datarepeater is located at project form.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMa7r.jpg)

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I copied the code in the Form_load() of Coordinator2 form, which works, but first gives an error.

Comment: I copied the code in the Form_load() of Coordinator2 form, which works, but first gives an error.
"Cannot clear table Project Info because ForeignKeyConstraint FK_Task Info_Project Info enforces constraints and there are child rows in Task Info."
It looks like, the Cascade on Delete causes this, but I need the cascade option for this relationship. it should not give this error, because I didn't try to delete a record individually, but just tried to refill the table adapter with updated data. and even tried to dispose and clean the table adapter, still gives the same error.